# ¿Cómo hacer un filtro para datos de una tabla en html?

Tags: html, postgresql, angular9

Tengo dos tablas relacionadas entre sí en una base de datos PostgreSQL, una tabla es de especies de verdura (Especie) y la otra de meses de siembra (MesSiembra), generando una especie de calendario en html. Quisiera realizar dos filtros, el más importante para mi sería por meses, donde sólo muestre las verduras que se pueden sembrar el mes elegido en el "select", es decir, aquellas verduras que no se siembre en dicho mes que no aparezca en el calendario. La opción de "Todos los meses" mostraría el calendario completo. Por otro lado, el otro filtro sería que muestre los meses de siembra para una especie elegida en el select. La opción de "Todas las especies" mostraría el calendario completo.

Aquí algo de código:

**calendario.component.html**

```
<h1>CALENDARIO DE SIEMBRA</h1>
<hr>
<h4>Filtrar por mes</h4>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <select class="form-control">
      <option *ngFor="let ml of mesesLista" [ngValue]="ml">{{ml}}</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <select class="form-control">
      <option *ngFor="let e of especies" [ngValue]="e">{{e.nombre}}</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
<hr>
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <thead class="thead-dark">
    <tr>
      <th>Especies</th>
      <th class="texto-mes" *ngFor="let m of meses">{{m}}</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let e of especies">
      <td>{{e.nombre}}</td>
      <td *ngFor="let m of meses;index as i">
        <div class="{{tieneMes(e.mesesSiembra,i)?'circulo':''}}"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**calendario.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Especie, EspecieService } from 'src/app/servicios/especie.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-calendario',
  templateUrl: './calendario.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./calendario.component.css']
})
export class CalendarioComponent implements OnInit {
  especies: Especie[] = [];
  

  constructor(private _servicioEspecie: EspecieService,
    private _router: Router ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this._servicioEspecie.get().subscribe(respuesta => {
      console.log(respuesta);
      this.especies = respuesta;
    });
  }
  mesesLista : string[]= ["Todos los meses","Enero","Febrero","Marzo","Abril","Mayo","Junio","Julio","Agosto","Septiembre","Octubre","Noviembre","Diciembre"];
  meses : string[] = ["Ene","Feb","Mar","Abr","May","Jun","Jul","Ago","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dic"];
tieneMes(meses : any[],index:number) : boolean{
    return meses.some(a => a.id == index + 1 );
 } 
}
```

Respuesta obtenida con un GET a Especies con Postman. Códico JSON:

```
[
    {
        "id": 49,
        "nombre": "Berenjena",
        "linkImagen": "https://i.ibb.co/C6xxY0w/Berenjena.jpg",
        "fechaRegistro": "2020-08-24T03:27:19.139+00:00",
        "descripcion": "La berenjena (Solanum melongena) es una planta de fruto comestible, generalmente anual, del género Solanum dentro de la familia de las solanáceas.",
        "dtype": "Especie",
        "diasGerminacionDesde": 15,
        "diasGerminacionHasta": 20,
        "distEntrePlantas": 40,
        "distEntreLineas": 70,
        "familia": {
            "id": 28,
            "nombre": "Solanáceas",
            "linkImagen": "https://i.ibb.co/F4BbJQK/Solan-ceas.jpg",
            "fechaRegistro": "2020-08-08T06:16:34.638+00:00",
            "descripcion": "Las solanáceas son una familia de plantas herbáceas con las hojas alternas, simples y sin estípulas pertenecientes al orden Solanales, de las dicotiledóneas.​",
            "dtype": "Familia"
        },
        "mesesSiembra": [
            {
                "id": 7,
                "nombre": "Julio"
            },
            {
                "id": 8,
                "nombre": "Agosto"
            },
            {
                "id": 9,
                "nombre": "Septiembre"
            },
            {
                "id": 10,
                "nombre": "Octubre"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 61,
        "nombre": "Cebolla",
        "linkImagen": "https://i.ibb.co/BPFgMbm/Cebolla.jpg",
        "fechaRegistro": "2020-08-27T17:15:38.235+00:00",
        "descripcion": "Allium cepa, comúnmente conocida como cebolla, es una planta herbácea bienal perteneciente a la familia de las amarilidáceas. Es la especie más cultivada del género Allium, el cual contiene varias especies que se denominan «cebollas» y que se cultivan como alimento. Ejemplos de las mismas son la cebolla de verdeo (Allium fistulosum), la cebolla escalonia (Allium ascalonicum) y la cebolla de hoja o ciboulette (Allium schoenoprasum).",
        "dtype": "Especie",
        "diasGerminacionDesde": 10,
        "diasGerminacionHasta": 25,
        "distEntrePlantas": 10,
        "distEntreLineas": 35,
        "familia": {
            "id": 31,
            "nombre": "Liliáceas",
            "linkImagen": "aaaaaaaaaab",
            "fechaRegistro": "2020-08-10T03:30:39.756+00:00",
            "descripcion": "fdghjkl",
            "dtype": "Familia"
        },
        "mesesSiembra": [
            {
                "id": 2,
                "nombre": "Febrero"
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "nombre": "Marzo"
            },
            {
                "id": 4,
                "nombre": "Abril"
            },
            {
                "id": 5,
                "nombre": "Mayo"
            },
            {
                "id": 6,
                "nombre": "Junio"
            },
            {
                "id": 7,
                "nombre": "Julio"
            },
            {
                "id": 8,
                "nombre": "Agosto"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 66,
        "nombre": "Pimiento",
        "linkImagen": "trghreth",
        "fechaRegistro": "2020-08-29T19:36:37.307+00:00",
        "descripcion": "erytyhjdrthyftyj",
        "dtype": "Especie",
        "diasGerminacionDesde": 10,
        "diasGerminacionHasta": 20,
        "distEntrePlantas": 20,
        "distEntreLineas": 40,
        "familia": {
            "id": 28,
            "nombre": "Solanáceas",
            "linkImagen": "https://i.ibb.co/F4BbJQK/Solan-ceas.jpg",
            "fechaRegistro": "2020-08-08T06:16:34.638+00:00",
            "descripcion": "Las solanáceas son una familia de plantas herbáceas con las hojas alternas, simples y sin estípulas pertenecientes al orden Solanales, de las dicotiledóneas.​",
            "dtype": "Familia"
        },
        "mesesSiembra": [
            {
                "id": 8,
                "nombre": "Agosto"
            },
            {
                "id": 9,
                "nombre": "Septiembre"
            },
            {
                "id": 10,
                "nombre": "Octubre"
            },
            {
                "id": 11,
                "nombre": "Noviembre"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 29,
        "nombre": "Tomate",
        "linkImagen": "https://i.ibb.co/2F6fPw2/Tomate.jpg",
        "fechaRegistro": "2020-08-08T06:23:23.103+00:00",
        "descripcion": "Solanum lycopersicum, cuyo fruto es el tomate, conocida comúnmente como tomatera, es una especie de planta herbácea del género Solanum de la familia Solanaceae.​​",
        "dtype": "Especie",
        "diasGerminacionDesde": 5,
        "diasGerminacionHasta": 8,
        "distEntrePlantas": 30,
        "distEntreLineas": 80,
        "familia": {
            "id": 28,
            "nombre": "Solanáceas",
            "linkImagen": "https://i.ibb.co/F4BbJQK/Solan-ceas.jpg",
            "fechaRegistro": "2020-08-08T06:16:34.638+00:00",
            "descripcion": "Las solanáceas son una familia de plantas herbáceas con las hojas alternas, simples y sin estípulas pertenecientes al orden Solanales, de las dicotiledóneas.​",
            "dtype": "Familia"
        },
        "mesesSiembra": [
            {
                "id": 7,
                "nombre": "Julio"
            },
            {
                "id": 8,
                "nombre": "Agosto"
            },
            {
                "id": 9,
                "nombre": "Septiembre"
            },
            {
                "id": 10,
                "nombre": "Octubre"
            },
            {
                "id": 11,
                "nombre": "Noviembre"
            },
            {
                "id": 12,
                "nombre": "Diciembre"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

**calendario.component.css**

```
.circulo {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: red;
  margin: auto;
}

.texto-mes {
  text-align: center;
}
```